# Extend a class plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I can't get the user variable from the main class loading a "child class" example:

```
//PLUGIN FILE
class father{

    var $user;

    function __construct() {
        add_action('plugins_loaded', array(&$this, 'loaded'));
    }

    function plugins_loaded(){
        global $wp_get_current_user;
        $this->user = wp_get_current_user();
    }
}

$plugin = new parent();
```

That was the plugin file.

```
//EXTEND CLASS
class child extends father{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function user_id(){
        echo $this->user->ID;
    }
}
```

That was the extend class.

```
//CONFIG FILE (DISPLAYED IN ADMIN PANEL)
$child = new child();
$user_id = $child->user->id;
$child->user_id();
```

And that was the config page.

I can't get the user id in the extended class, but yes in the father class.

Why and how i can solve it?

Comment: I assume that 'class child extends parent' should have read 'class child extends father'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class father {
    var $user;
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'set_user' ) );
    }
    function set_user() {
        $this->user = wp_get_current_user();
    }
}

class child extends father {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function user_id(){
        return $this->user->ID;
    }
}

$father = new father();
$child = new child();

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'test_stuff' );
function test_stuff() {
    global $child;
    print '<pre>Child: ' . print_r( $child->user_id(), true ) . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Yeah but if child had a function that uses $this->user->ID it return an empty value. Code edited with example.

Comment: I just updated my answer. I'm not having a problem with the code. Perhaps 'plugins_loaded' is too early to be getting the user data? 'init' works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure? because wp_get_current_user() is in pluggable.php and it is loaded once all plugins are loaded so it should throw an error on init.

Comment: Loading plugins is one of the first things that WordPress does ... init fires after the set_current_user hook. plugins_loaded fires before set_current_user. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Ahhh i found why. I was creating the instance of child on the settings page. For some reason that doesn't work there. But i created the instance in the plugin file and the used global in the settings page, that worked.
Still that give me a bad taste in my mouth...i'm not too happy with the solution.